# Display two windows at the same time for python

Tags: python

I have a wide range guessing game, and I want to try and have two windows displaying at the same time so that the main window has the code where the user guesses the number, but then another smaller window next to it so that it can record the numbers guessed and the results/hints. But then the second window would also need to be able to be updated every time the user guesses a number...

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HvAf.png) is an example to show what I mean.

Is this possible?

Thank you!

-PJ

Comment: The image shows two instances of IDLE Shells.  You could potentially run IDLE twice from a program, but this would be worse that the solutions given in the link above.  GUI frameworks are designed for problems needing multiple displays.